# VIS.js - Network - All nodes crowded together when first load

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

When initialing loading the vis network chart, all nodes crowded together, due to some reason I could not set layout improvedLayout to true, and also I need to set physics to disable.

here is my option setting, please advise how I can let the nodes positioned well within the following option setting.

```
var options = {
    "edges": {
        "smooth": { "forceDirection": "none" }
    },
    "physics": { "enabled": false, "minVelocity": 0.75 },
    "layout": { improvedLayout: _improvedLayout }
}
```

initialing loading, all nodes stay together which makes me hard to see them:

[image]

with `improvedLayout` set to true, it displays well, but the performance is really bad I could not set it in this way.

[image]

here is an example: I have 77 edges and 65 nodes, it took 7-8 seconds to draw the network picture when I set improvedLayout to true, is that normal?

Comment: Why disable the physics?

Comment: The reason for disabling physics is avoid nodes jumping or unexpected movement, @Thebluefis

Comment: Could you share your nodes and edges, maybe make a fiddle? With this small amount of nodes, performance shouldn't be any closer of being a problem...

Comment: Have you tried hiding graph, disabling physics are it get relaxed and showing the result?

Comment: @YakovL Could you please give a little detail on hiding graph? I'd like to keep the nodes and edges on the chart. basically any ideas can improve the loading speed with a good format on the chart will help.

Comment: Well, I mean adding `display: none;` to the graph's container. As for improving the speed of relaxation, that's not trivial, you should try to adjust various params of physics.. see http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html